# How to test slow background thread on iOS Device

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm working with legacy code that has a strange race condition. It sets up a background thread, goes into `handleLogin` which then detects if it is in the background. If it is, then it calls itself on the main thread while quitting out. This causes the background thread to exit the method and set a variable that is used in the main thread. We have reports of users seeing an error that can happen from this race condition, but they see it consistently. How do you force the background thread on an iOS device to perform significantly slower than the main thread?

Relevant code:

```
- (void)performLogin
{
  [AppDelegate instance].condition = 0
  if ([NSThread isMainThread])
  {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performLogin) withObject:nil];
    return;
  }

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  //Code to handle Login logic removed//
  [self handleLogin];
  [AppDelegate instance].condition = 1;
  [pool release];
}

- (void)handleLogin
{
  if (![NSThread isMainThread])
  {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleLogin) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
  }

  ...

  if ([AppDelegate instance].condition == 0)
  {
     Perform logic
  }
}
```

The issue specifically is that `condition` is set to 0 before and the code relies on it being set to 1 to function properly. It's almost always set to 1 because the background finishes before the main thread gets to that point, but we have reports that some users consistently have `condition` set to 0 by the time the main thread hits the conditional in `handleLogin`. I've duplicated this issue by forcing the background thread to stall long enough for the main thread to finish executing.

How can I do this naturally on an iOS device? I've redesigned the code but need to find a way to reproduce this naturally for verification of the fix :)

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but may address your real problem:  1)  If you're accessing a variable in more than one thread, you should protect access to it via @synchronize.  2)  The first line of performLogin should probably be `[AppDelegate instance].condition = 0;` with a single equal instead of with two.

Comment: Hey David! That was actually a copying mistake, I've had to change the code when putting it on here. I agree with the @synchronizing the variable if accessing from more than one thread. I'm actually rewriting the code to prevent this issue but trying to figure out how our QA can reproduce the issue to verify the fix :)

Comment: I would recommend to redesign the code: make it asynchronous, and use dispatch lib. It would be so easy.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Totally agreed, but I also need to find a way for our QA team to be able to reproduce this for verifying the fix. It's something we've never been able to reproduce in-house so getting them to see it in person would be a huge confidence booster for passing the code into prod

Comment: If the QA team would know C and C++ better, they would realize by looking over the code that it leads to "undefined behavior" (due to accessing a variable from different threads without using synchronization primitives) ;)   You can this look up in the C and C++ specifications - which is valid for Objective-C in this regard, too.

Comment: @LyricalPanda see the answer below.  Since the problem is reproducible in the field and not so much onsite, it seems likely it's a latency issue, which can be reproduced using Network Link Conditioner.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing a network-based application, one thing to add to your arsenal of development and quality process is Apple's Network Link Conditioner, it allows you to degrade the perceived performance of the network connection to induce things like latency and timing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I actually didn't know this existed and throttled using Charles before. I tried various network settings (including coming from 100% packetloss to bad connection) but haven't been able to reproduce it yet. Honestly it really sounds like the issue lies in some phones having their background thread be  significantly slower than the main thread as this part of the logic doesn't require an internet connection. I'll keep trying to reproduce though using this tool!